# I need to count token from my input text using @dqbd/tiktoken library using react JS. If it is possible?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I was developing project using React JS. The problem is I cant count token from my input text using **@dqbd/tiktoken library.** alternate functions are working for count token. but I need **@dqbd/tiktoken.** and one more doubt if it is possible to count token use this library?

I was tried but the error is **Import as 'countToken' was not found in that library**

```
import React from 'react';
import { countTokens } from '@dqbd/tiktoken';

const TokenCounter = () => {
  const inputText = "Your input text goes here.";
  const tokenCount = countTokens(inputText);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Input Text: {inputText}</p>
      <p>Token Count: {tokenCount}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TokenCounter;
```

Comment: did it worked in for the react js project?

Comment: Yes Its worked well